# <Question> component displaying different types of questions failing type guard

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My type guard is the value of the `type` property in the question. For example, `radio` vs `text`:

```
interface BaseQuestionType {
  label?: string
}
export type RadioQuestionType = BaseQuestionType & {
  type: 'radio'
}
export type TextQuestionType = BaseQuestionType & {
  type: 'text' | 'textarea'
}
export type QuestionType =
  | RadioQuestionType
  | TextQuestionType
```

While using it, Typescript complains that `RadioQuestionType` is being assigned to `TextQuestionType`. I'd like it to handle being passed any `QuestionType`.

```
  <Question
    question={QUESTION_MAP[currentQuestionId] as QuestionType} // ERROR HIGHLIGHTS THIS LINE
  />
  // ...
interface BaseQuestionPropsType<TAnswerMap> {
  question: QuestionType
}
type TextQuestionPropsType<TAnswerMap> = BaseQuestionPropsType<TAnswerMap> & {
  question: TextQuestionType
}

type RadioQuestionPropsType<TAnswerMap> = BaseQuestionPropsType<TAnswerMap> & {
  question: RadioQuestionType
}
type PropsType<TAnswerMap> =
  | RadioQuestionPropsType<TAnswerMap>
  | TextQuestionPropsType<TAnswerMap>

type TAnswerMap = Record<string, unknown>
const Question: React.FC<PropsType<TAnswerMap>> = props => { /* ... */ }
```

Here's the full Typescript error:

```
Types of property 'question' are incompatible.
      Type 'QuestionType' is not assignable to type 'TextQuestionType'.
        Type 'RadioQuestionType' is not assignable to type 'TextQuestionType'.
          Type 'RadioQuestionType' is not assignable to type '{ type: "textarea" | "text"; }'.
            Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
              Type '"radio"' is not assignable to type '"textarea" | "text"'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Might be because `type` is a reserved keyword in TypeScript, and you are using it as a property. Can you try changing this to something else, e.g. `typ`?

Comment: Nope that's not the issue. @CasDekkers

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the `PropsType<TAnswerMap>` interface. In your Question component,  you can use this instead:

```
const Question: React.FC<BaseQuestionPropsType<TAnswerMap>> = props => { /* ... */ }
```

The `BaseQuestionPropsType` already accomodates `QuestionType` in the `question` field.

The compiler can only decide between 2 types in a union if there is a unique "literal" type to differentiate between them. Otherwise, it will fail to do so and you must accomodate all the types in the union. Read [discriminating unions from the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

Answer (score 1):

You have an overload here for the union type in the sense that the check for QuestionType is not unique! An object of type `BaseQuestionType` might at the same time be an object of type `RadioQuestionType` or `TextQuestionType`.

You could define:

```
interface BaseQuestionType {
  label?: string;
  type: never;
}
```

if you want to fix it while keeping the given structure. However, questions being either of type `RadioQuestionType` or `TextQuestionType` would no longer be of type `BaseQuestionType`, which is what you need for safe type guarding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the type cast (`as QuestionType`) is the problem. I've re-created your example in a : [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA3AB2MWUBeWcAQmlgIoCuWVDGAQGAFQCeYDgG8acOABtkAIyxKA-AC44wqIwDmNAL40sAD0iw4MaRwzIAJqIFCRYqTLgBeLjzdhUQl7OAAyOHlFOxldCmdRWjNLa3gYjnFLGECPEO8-blQ%20QSDPUIio23s45gsYMjgAH3JamGRKZCTzK2g00Jzgrw4fBSbMBIgBsplR5sy6qbysOnomFjZcDkLi92CABWIwVCGAHnEAQQZUAHcWAFlkMAA%20SNGARxLc3UWh0xp0uDzbKffaHY72M6XG73R4vAoBEFiA4QI6nC5XW5QB7PcKvRQfXZiXRAn72P7-UKOFyTREMZGoiHo6FY2G%20fxFRb08EySEYmE4irvWm6KmuWm-MwArloqGY7Fw2bjamcsEyvks56Kkm06WM2X8p50AFMuWPNnYXDQJwnfRGAA0cH4DAA1gwINcGIbLVd4IsRVQYAA6ABiAGETrqeSaDXC4GAwb4Xgx%20EolCsAPTpuDXaDO1A0RYAClkcAJpQYuhL6RqWQaJhMAEo6Jns7n897hKXvuLQn4q9UWrW4GYiyWy19S8OmzQO-A3gAmNn92KDup1lDoUkzUel4WlxeNoA)

```
// works
Question({ question: { type: 'text' }})

// works
const q: QuestionType = { type: 'text' }
Question({ question: q })

// doesn't work
const q2 = { type: 'text' } as QuestionType
Question({ question: q2 })
```

I don't know what you have in your `QUESTION_MAP` or why the type cast is necessary, but that seems to be the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Hassan Naqvi's answer,

The issue is the Component prop type defintion `PropsType<TAnswerMap>`. You wouldn't try to map the incoming definition to another definition.

The union type `QuestionType` is already doing this. You are saying the question type is in the shape of `RadioQuestionType` OR `TextQuestionType`.

The Question component basically expects one `question` input property of type `QuestionType`.

So your input field models could be written like this:

```js
interface BaseQuestionType {
  label?: string;
}
export interface RadioQuestionType extends BaseQuestionType {
  type: "radio";
}
export interface TextQuestionType extends BaseQuestionType {
  type: "text" | "textarea";
}

export type QuestionType = RadioQuestionType | TextQuestionType;
```

And the question component could just have one interface for it's expected input props.

```js
interface QuestionProps {
  question: QuestionType;
}

const Question: React.FC<QuestionProps> = props => {
  // This is how you could discriminate the type:
  switch (props?.question?.type) {
    case 'textarea':
    case 'text':
      return <h1>{props?.question?.type} Type!</h1>;
    case 'radio':
      return <h1>{props?.question?.type} Type!</h1>;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fddojn?file=Question.tsx)